# Подсчет данных при изменении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два компонента: текстовое поле и выпадающий список.
Хочу настроить связь между ними, как итог необходимо при изменении складывать значение компонента, в примитивном виде у меня это выглядит так

```
var sum=0;
$('#cpu').change(function(event) {
        var val=parseInt($(this).val());
    var itog=val*2;
    sum+=itog;
    $("#itog").text(sum);
});

$("#txt").keyup(function (e) {
        var val=parseInt($(this).val());    
        sum+=val;
        $("#itog").text(sum);
    })
```

В таком виде от все плюсует. А мне нужно чтобы только последние значения

Например:
вводим 5 в поле и выбираем 1000 в выпадающем списке

- он должен в списке умножить значение на 2
- прибавить значение текстового поля

Сейчас значение плюсуются и плюсуются, проблема в том,как сделать так, что бы они перезаписывались, а не добавлялись
https://jsfiddle.net/ex7aze3z/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, лучше сделать так [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/ac9fjskj/2/).

```js
function calculateSum(cpuVal, txtVal) {
  var sum = (parseFloat(cpuVal) || 0) * 2 + (parseFloat(txtVal) || 0); // проверка на NaN
  $("#itog").text(sum);
}

$('#cpu').change(function() {
  calculateSum($("#cpu").val(), $("#txt").val());
});

$("#txt").on("input", function() {
  calculateSum($("#cpu").val(), $("#txt").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="число" id="txt" value="1" type="text" class="number-txtbox validate">

<!------------------------->

<select id="cpu" class="selection icons">
 <option value="0" disabled selected>Выберите </option>
 <option value="260" >260 Р</option>
 <option value="450"> 450 Р</option>
 <option value="850">850 Р</option>
 <option value="1000"> 1000 Р</option> 
</select>

<p id="itog"></p>
```

Только учтите, что вместо события `keyup` лучше использовать событие `input`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно просто добавить обнуление переменной `sum`при смене значения в `select`

```
var sum=0;
$('#cpu').change(function(event) {
    sum = 0; //обнуление переменной при смене значения
    var val=parseInt($(this).val());
    var itog=val*2;
    sum+=itog;
    $("#itog").text(sum);
});

$("#txt").keyup(function (e) {
    var val=parseInt($(this).val());    
    sum+=val;
    $("#itog").text(sum);
})
```

Comment: Но в таком случае, если менять значение в `#txt`, то все равно будет увеличиваться значение постоянно.